# I would like to wipe my SSD in a dual boot and dual hard drive scenario. I want to just wipe my boot drive (The SSD) and have just Windows 10 only

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssd, multi-boot

How would I accomplish this without losing any data on my secondary hard drive?
I am considering to use the built in Windows 10 reset tool but I am reluctant incase it accidentally wipes the second hard drive.
I would like to add, I am doing this to free space on my SSD because I never use ubuntu anymore, and just to make sure I can get rid of any unused programs on my computer and potentially get better performance because I initially set up this computer 4 years ago and I use it a lot.

Comment: Remove your secondary hard drive (a good idea in any reset) and then reinstall Windows 10 on the SSD. You cannot lose any data on the secondary hard drive this way.

Comment: They should be able to boot a live CD and use gparted. It might depend on which OS was installed first (the OS to keep should be the first partition, they could expand the partition if that was the case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With only the drive you want to change connected, boot a Live CD and run gparted. Right click the partition you want to delete and delete it. If the partition to keep is on the left (first partition) you can right click and select expand. I don't think you can do it if the OS to keep is not the first partition.

Comment: I have used GParted to do this in reverse,I used it to shrink the Windows Partition to make space for new Linux partition.

Comment: Thank you for accepting my answer